# TypeError: arr[idx] is not a function

Tags: node.js

```
var validate = require('validate-fields')();
var series = require('async-series');


exports.calculateGstBaseOnInput = function(req, res,next) {
    for(var item of req.body.so_items) {
        req.productid = item.productid;
        req.qty = item.qty;
        series([
            getitemdetail(null,req,res),
        ], function (error, success) {
            res.json({error : error, success : success});
        });
     }
    res.json({status : 'gst', statusMessage : 'gst success'});

}

getitemdetail =function(req,res)
{
    console.log(req.productid);
    console.log(req.qty);

}
```

Error :

> 2222 5 TypeError: arr[idx] is not a function
>       at handleItem (D:\node\node_modules\async-series\index.js:14:13)
>       at series (D:\node\node_modules\async-series\index.js:30:3)
>       at exports.calculateGstBaseOnInput (D:\node\app\addorder.js:48:9)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (D:\node\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Query._callback (D:\node\app\addorder.js:40:21)
>       at Query.Sequence.end (D:\node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:88:24)
>       at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (D:\node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:139:8)
>       at Query.EofPacket (D:\node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:123:8)
>       at Protocol._parsePacket (D:\node\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:279:23)

Comment: What is your question? I'd recommend to read the documentation of the package you are using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-series . You are passing the wrong arguments to the function.

Comment: What is the done argument? how to pass more arguments? how do i call functions within the array instead of defining it?  Are you saying the answer to all these questions are there in the link provided? I'd recommend you to read how to create documentation for the package.

Comment: Why should I create documentation for that module? It's not mine. If you find the documentation lacking, why did you choose this module in the first place? *"What is the done argument?"* It looks like `done` needs to be called in order to tell `series` that the function is "done", i.e. that it can move to the next function. *"how do i call functions within the array instead of defining it?"* You don't. The point of `series` is that it will call async functions *in series* for you. You are not calling the function, `series` calls the function. You just give it the functions that it should call.

Comment: However, if you don't actually have multiple asynchronous functions that need to be called in series, then there is no point in using that module.

Comment: @FelixKling i didn't ask you to create but to read how to create. This will help you understand, whether the documentation is good enough for anyone to use the product/feature. So that you will not go ahead and support anything just becuase you were able use it without any problem.

Comment: @FelixKling even you are sure about what the done is for. you too assume it is called in order to tell series that the function is done. This is what good documentation eliminates. No assumption.

Comment: Sure. That's the convention. To know what it really does one would need to look at the source code. But anyone can do that: https://github.com/hughsk/async-series/blob/4147b09c3a6c2c089c31a87427c746aa6b121ad7/index.js

Comment: @FelixKling function calls can be made as opposed to your comment. see the answer by suresh.

Comment: This doesn't contradict my comment. Of course you can do whatever you want inside the function you pass to `series`, including calling other functions (I thought that's clear). All I said was that you need to pass it a function, not call the function and pass its return value (like in your original code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`series` except an array of function, try changing your code like below

```
exports.calculateGstBaseOnInput = function(req, res,next) {
  for(var item of req.body.so_items) {
    req.productid = item.productid;
    req.qty = item.qty;
    series([function(done){
      getitemdetail(null,req,res);
      done();
    }], function (error, success) {
        res.json({error : error, success : success});
    });
  }
  res.json({status : 'gst', statusMessage : 'gst success'});
}
```

for more information, please refer - https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-series#user-content-usage

Comment: Thanks Suresh. It worked. After every function call i should call done()?

Comment: However, this only works in this example because `getitemdetail` is actually synchronous. If it was asynchronous things would be different of course.

Comment: Well thats what i was going for. i dont really find a need to use series if i dont want things to be synchronous.

Comment: `done` is a call to next `function` for `asyn-series` calls and you have to call it after the successful operation for each `function` in `asyn-series` `array`. Alos as @FelixKling mentioned `getitemdetail` is synchronous function(as you are only printing logs). In case that's asynchronous then you have to call `done` `function` inside async callback

Comment: You can also use `async` has good warapper support on async callback handlings. https://github.com/caolan/async